# App registered with Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy permissions in azure has additional permission on consent page

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, microsoft-graph-api

App registered with Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy permissions in azure has additional permission on consent page.

1. I registered an app in portal.azure.com with application permission 'Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy'
2. when i try to get the consent using https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=myid&redirect_uri=redirecturl&state=state1234&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

i get additional permission(sign in and read user profile) displayed on consent page. I did not set that permission, but it is still displayed on consent page. how can i avoid this using admin consent endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue.

[image]

I suppose that the `sign in and read user profile` is used to check if the user account is the admin.

Actually, even if you click the `Accept` button, the `sign in and read user profile` permission will not be granted for the service principal(Enterprise Application), so don't worry about that.

Check the `service principal(Enterprise Application)`, there is just `Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy`.

[image]

Comment: But, doesn't it give wrong impression to the admin who signs in and give consent??

Comment: Im glad that you were able to reproduce it. If you give consent and again call adminconsent endpoint, this consent page reappears again. Shouldn't it skip the consent page if admin already given the consent to the same app?

Comment: @bhanu7k 1.Yes.But there's no doc mentions it. 2.Because the `sign in and read user profile` was not consented for the app, so the consent page will reappear again. If you want to skip the page, you could add the `User.Read` manually in the API Permission.

Comment: i found about ```sign in and read user profile``` in docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent

Comment: @Parmela Peng, i tried enabling ```User.Read``` in delegated permission for my app, Still consent page appears whenever i hit adminconsent endpoint

Comment: @bhanu7k Per my test, the admin consent url will always promote the page, even if you already consent the permissions.If you try with the [auth code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow), login with the normal user, he will not need to consent the permissions again.

Comment: Yes that is exactly what was happening. Unfortunately it is not mentioned in docs anywhere.

Comment: @bhanu7k Maybe related to the `Note` in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#requesting-individual-user-consent), see https://i.stack.imgur.com/GrxpN.png

Comment: Hi @PamelaPeng. Would you be able to take a look at this question, please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69434600/the-app-needs-access-to-a-service-api-appid-that-your-organization-has-not